# Compare columns data at the same group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem that I can't convert into sql
Say I have 2 tables table1 and table2 such that 
table1 of 3 columns (P, L, T) that represents before transfer state

```
P1 L1 t1
P1 L1 t2
P1 L2 t3
P2 L5 t4
P2 L5 t5
P2 L6 t6
```

Table2 of 3 columns (P, L, T) that represents after transfer

```
P1 L3 t1
P1 L3 t2
P1 L4 t3 
P2 L15 t4
P2 L16 t5
P2 L16 t6
```

The only difference between table1 and table2 is column L. We will have the same P and T columns.
I would like to select the p such that the Ts that belong to the same old L are still belong to the same new L where count of Ts grouped by L > 1.

```
**Case** (table1)t1,t2 At L1(old L) and (Table2)t1, t2 At L3(new L). Count of T grouped by L =2  and t1, t2 belong to same L group then return P.

**Case** table1: t3 at L2 and table2: t3 at L4. Count of T grouped by L =1 then ignore P.

**Case** (table1)t4,t5 At L5(old L) and (Table2)t4, t5 At L15 and L16(new L). Count of T grouped by L =2  but t4, t5 belong to different L group then ignore P.
```

I need to compare both count(T) and Ts group by L and return P
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a table variable that contains the invalid rows 
the table variable of P, T and selected from table1 join table2 group by table1.p , table1.L

```
Drop table table1
Drop table Table2
create table table1
(
P bigint, L bigINt, T BigInt
)
create table table2
(
P bigint, L bigINt, T BigInt
)
Declare @Invalid_Ps table(P BIGINT, L BIGINT)
Insert INTO @Invalid_Ps (P, L)
Select a.Tbl1P ,a.Tbl1L
FROM
(Select tbl1.P as Tbl1P, tbl1.L as Tbl1L,Tbl2.L as Tbl2L , Tbl1.T as Tbl1T
from Table1 as tbl1 Join Table2 as tbl2
ON tbl1.P = Tbl2.P
Group By tbl1.P, tbl1.L,Tbl2.L, Tbl1.T
) a
 GROUp BY a.Tbl1P,a.Tbl1L
Having (SUM(a.Tbl2L) IS NULL OR count(distinct a.Tbl2L) <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand the entire requirement, but this is how you can select rows where there are more than one value of `T` per same values of `P` and `L`:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY P, L)
  FROM table1
)
SELECT P, L, T
FROM counted
WHERE cnt > 1
;
```

Then, since, according to your post, `table2` *‘will have the same P and T columns’* and also, as per your comment, *‘T is unique per P’*, you can join the resulting set of the above query to `table2` on the columns `P` and `T`. That way you will be able to find out which `L` values in `table1` changed to which `L` values in `table2`:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY P, L)
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT
  t1.P,
  t1.L AS OldL,
  t2.L AS NewL,
  t1.T
FROM counted t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.P = t2.P AND t1.T = t2.T
WHERE t1.cnt > 1
;
```